# UIButton animation ontarget self

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am working on a app with two UIButtons which have to change size and color when they are pressed. My code is:

```
    UIButton *Answer1Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    UIButton *Answer2Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [Answer1Button addTarget:self action:@selector(Answer1Action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [Answer2Button addTarget:self action:@selector(Answer2Action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [Answer1Button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [Answer2Button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    Answer1Button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45);
    Answer2Button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 45);
```

And the function I created for it:

```
-(void)Answer1Action{


[UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

self.alpha = 0.5;

[UIButton commitAnimations];    
}
```

The problem I encounter right now, is when I press the UIButton the function is called but the self.alpha affects the entire UIView in which the button is located in.

I'm still a rookie with Objective-C so I'm thinking it is probably something simple I forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `self.alpha = 0.5;`, here self is not your button. You should set your button:

```
Answer1Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

Answer1Button.alpha = 0.5;
```

But this is not the best practice. You can send your button to the handler method as param:
(Variable and method names should not start with capital letter in ObjC.)

```
[answer1Button addTarget:self action:@selector(answer1Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And use the sender button as parameter in your handler method:

```
-(void)answer1Action:(id)sender{
UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*)sender;

[UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

myButton.alpha = 0.5;

[UIButton commitAnimations];    
}
```

Comment: Great this works fine, thanks! And also thanks for the capital letter notice!

Comment: And how can I also change the backgroundColor of the answer2Button in the answer1Action?

Comment: You should create variables for your buttons. I recommend you to use @property.

Answer (score 3):

```
[Answer1Button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[Answer1Button setAlpha:0.5];

//Include QuartzCore framework and import it to your viewController.h,and write the below line along with the above code to change the size and to do many animations.

Answer1Button.layer.affineTransform=CGAffineTransformScale(Answer1Button.transform, 1.2, 1.2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set button alpha instead of self.alpha=0.5;

```
-(void)Answer1Action{


   [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
   self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

   Answer1Button.alpha = 0.5;

  [UIButton commitAnimations];    
    }
```

Comment: Whenever I try to change self to Answer1Button I'm getting a use of undeclared identifier. So then my question would be, how can I call the Answer1Button in the Answer1Action?

Comment: You have to declare Answer1Button globally, then you will not get error as undeclared identifier.

Comment: in your .h file -   UIButton * Answer1Button;   and use that in .m, then it will work.  ie in .m it will be like this - Answer1Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];